# How to expose REST API HAL format pagination

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-web-api, hateoas

How should I expose pagination for a REST API by using HAL format, should I just wrap everything in another HAL formatted object with pagination metadata or ?

Is there a suggested pagination format under REST API HAL format ?

UPDATE

Example without the pagination

```
[
    {
        "Id": "SomeId",
        "Attribute": 5,
        "_links": {
            "User": { "href": "http://mywebapi/etc", "templated": true }
        },
        "_embedded": { "User": { "Id": "SomeId","_links": {},"_embedded": {}} }
    },
    {
        "Id": "SomeId",
        "Attribute": 5,
        "_links": {
            "User": { "href": "http://mywebapi/etc", "templated": true }
        },
        "_embedded": { "User": { "Id": "SomeId","_links": {},"_embedded": {}} }
    }
]
```

Example with the pagination

```
{
    "_embedded": { 
    "items":
    [
        {
            "Id": "SomeId",
            "Attribute": 5,
            "_links": {
                "User": { "href": "http://mywebapi/etc", "templated": true }
            },
            "_embedded": { "User": { "Id": "SomeId","_links": {},"_embedded": {}} }
        },
        {
            "Id": "SomeId",
            "Attribute": 5,
            "_links": {
                "User": { "href": "http://mywebapi/etc", "templated": true }
            },
            "_embedded": { "User": { "Id": "SomeId","_links": {},"_embedded": {}} }
        }
    ]},
    "_links": {
        "next": "next link",
        "previous": "next link"
    },
    "_totalCount": "100"
}
```

It this a good practice or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use links with rel="next" and rel="previous"

Comment: What about the total record count ? Should I put it just in the _links of the wrapped object or I don't need wrapped object ?

Comment: @khorvat Not sure what you mean by "wrapped object" but your example looks good to me.  Probably should add a self link to the _links object in the root resource object and in your embeded resources.  Also the array should be called 'item' not 'items'.  The name represents the link relation to the embedded resources in the array.   'item' is a standardized link relation registered with IANA.

Comment: well I'm new to HAL so I'm still figuring out everything. By wrapped object I just meant the json top level object holding the __embedded_, _item_ & __links_ ... I have self and few other links in my real representation of HAL so I think everything is explained.

Answer (score 4):

By the way you have an example in proper HAL RFC

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06#section-6

```
 "_links": {
   "self": { "href": "/orders" },
   "next": { "href": "/orders?page=2" },
   "find": { "href": "/orders{?id}", "templated": true }
 }
```

What i am not sure is about "_totalCount" ... i am also figuring out what would be the best way to incude a totalCount attribute in HAL format

Comment: If you find anything interesting about total count let me know.

Comment: The `_totalCount` is fine as a direct property to the collection. I would probably choose a more predictable and easy to remember name though, like `count` (bonus point as most developer familiar with SQL can relate).

Answer (score 1):

`_totalcount` can be problematic. Is it inherent property of the resource you return? Most likely not.

If you do have it, then you will be forced to provide this value *every time* for *every page of the resource*. If the total collection is very large, it will become necessary to store the count somewhere to satisfy the API. In many cases, the count may be harder to get. For example, if you implement based on other services that provide continuation token, getting `_totalcount` populated will become hard. If you have SQL table, it might be fairly easy to get but it comes at a cost too.

Is it really valuable for the client or UI? I would avoid if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly elaborate how this post helps to solve the problem faced by asker. In case of doubts and queries, it is recommended to make use of comments, once you earn enough reputations. You can always comment on your own posts.